# How gravity acts equals on all bodies irrespective of their masses

Tags: general-relativity

According to Einstein's theory of relativity, gravity is a space time fabric: it acts equally irrespective of masses; space is pushing objectives down. If it happens, why are gasses upper in the atmosphere and liquids on Earth  and Earth consists of solids? Why cannot gasses and liquids be mixed together at all levels?

Comment: The mass of an object determines how much it effects the "space time fabric". In the classical sense, the force of gravity depends on both masses. Why are you saying the mass does not matter?

Comment: I thinmk you are not a native English speaker.  Your question might be easier to understand if you use [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/).

Comment: If we take to different massive bodies falling from same height they fall at same rate irrespective of their masses ...

Comment: Exactly. $F=ma$ So if they are falling with the same acceleration, it must be that the more massive an object is, the larger the gravitational force on it is. This turns out to be the case. The gravitational force is directly proportional to both masses.

Comment: Suppose F is G i.e gravitational force of earth than G=m1*a and G=m2*a how this is valid ... here m1 and m2 are masses falling from same height

Comment: Near the surface of the earth the gravitational force is given by $F = G\frac{M_E m}{(R_E +h)^2} = a m$ where $a=G\frac{M_E }{(R_E +h)^2}$. As can be seen the acceleration only depends on the mass of earth $M_E$,  the distance $R_E+h$, and $G$.

Comment: In $G=m_1a$, where $m_1$ is falling, $G$ is proportional to $m_1$. In $G=m_2a$, where $m_2$ is falling, $G$ is proportional to $m_2$. In either case the mass cancels and we have the same acceleration.

Comment: I recommend you think of this in terms of classical theories and newtonian gravity and similar stuff. There is no need for GR, and SR is completely unrelated. I'm not removing the GR tag since that's drastic (I will remove SR), but I think you should seriously consider that. This can easily be explained with general discussions of newtonian gravity and the kinds of intermolecular forces. Remember that gravitational force is dependent upon the mass, and acceleration due to gravity is constant for the scales you're considering, irrespective of the description of gravity.

Comment: @Chair basically I am working on unified field theory ... like Einstein theory of everything... I combined three forces n left with gravity so I am trying better understanding of it...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the fact you're referring to, that gravity "acts equally irrespective of the mass" of the object, does not arise just with General Relativity, but was already discovered by Galileo in the 16th century. A 1kg object and a 10kg object, thrown from a tower, will land at the same time at the bottom of that tower. According to the legend, this is the experiment Galileo performed, from the leaning tower of Pisa. (The friction with air will actually prevent this experiment from working properly, but it will work in vacuum!)

This means, concisely, that all object fall with the same **acceleration** due to gravity. This acceleration, on Earth, is roughly equal to $g=9.8 m/s^2$.

However, this is about accelerations, not forces. Because force equals mass times acceleration, $F = ma$, then the "force of gravity", which is also called **weight**, does depend on mass: $F_{weight}= mg$.

Now, force is the measure we're looking for when determining how different things interact, how much they can "push towards the bottom".

Comment: In one experiment i.e person in lift moving down and rope suddenly broken..idea come to Einstein mind space is pushing objects down... it means gravity is due to space time fabric